# Checking to see how often a method is executed in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, events

I was wondering if its possible to check how frequently, in terms of an accurate timespan, a certain method gets executed in C#?

For example I have a device (a microphone), and once I start the microphone, its `StartCollectingSamples` event is fired which will in turn start invoking the `Microphone_CollectSampleData()` method.

How can I check how frequently this event is being raised? I place a breakpoint on `Microphone_CollectSampleData()` and it seems to get executed very frequently, possible 2/3 times a second, but how can I get that accurate time value?

Comment: Put a static counter in the function?

Comment: Yea, I did this before, the method seems to be executing 600 times in 30 seconds, so every 20 milliseconds. thanks.

Comment: That's every 50 milliseconds, or 20 times per second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the version of the visual studio you got, you can use the [provided profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx), to analyze how many time each method is executed, how long it runs, etc.
There are other, non microsoft products, which aim to do the same, such as antz profiler, but they usually cost money after a trial period.

Comment: thanks, I have VS 2010 professional. So unfortunately it seems that I can't use this feature.

Comment: Maybe you can try [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/446908/1394380), as recommended by the SO community. i personally didnt try it, but it seems people have good opinions on it.